# .NET WebBrowser Control Not Displaying Web Page Graphics

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm using a WebBrowser control within a .NET Forms app, which will be used to display a particular web page from my customer's intranet.  When I launch the app, it displays the page, but in a very ugly format with no graphics, etc.

However, when I pull up the full Internet Explorer browser and go to the same URL, after a pause where the title bar says "Logging in", it loads the page normally with all graphics.   And *then*, when I re-launch the .NET app, the WebBrowser control displays the page correctly, with the graphics.   If I clear the IE Temporary Internet Files, the app reverts to the ugly no-graphics view, so the WebBrowser control is apparently using images from the local IE cache vice downloading them.

I have played with the IE Emulation mode (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION) to make sure the app's WebBrowser control is in IE11 mode, to no avail.   I wanted to try to use the new [WebView2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/) Nuget package which uses Edge vice IE, but my customer is not ready to use a pre-release package quite yet.

Any ideas?   I've looked through the settings for the WebBrowser control, but don't see anything obvious. I suspect that it might have something to do with authentication, since the WebBrowser control displays the page immediately, but IE pauses for a bit saying "logging in", and then displays the page.

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue so that we can have a better understading of the issue. We can't locate the issue with only the text description. Besides, if the displaying page is owned by you, you can try to add this line in html `<head>`: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`.

Comment: There is very little to show.  I'm simply setting the URI as shown below, though I'm using an Intranet site for this customer.  I've also tried playing with the .ScriptErrorsSuppressed boolean.  

I do not have access to the displaying page.  

`webBrowser.URL = new Uri("https://www.bing.com");`

Comment: I ues `webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.bing.com")` and it can show the page correctly. Dose the issue only occur with that intranet site or with all web sites? If you don't log in in the full Internet Explorer browser, will it show the ugly no-graphics view? I think first you need to determine whether it's an IE mode issue or it's an authentication issue.